# jqGrid is not mapping json string

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

I've done the following code for binding `jqGrid`:

```
function fnAddDetails() {
            debugger;
            var content = {};
            content.name = $("#txtName").val();
            //content.dob = $("#txtDOB").val();
            content.group = $("#ddlGroup option:selected").text();
            content.active = "InActive";
            content.age = age;
            if ($("#chkActive").attr("checked")) {
                content.active = "Active";
            }
            var jsonText = JSON.stringify(content);
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Test_sspl142_jQuery_JavaScript.aspx/GetDate",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: jsonText,
                success: function(data) {
                    debugger;
                    var dataget = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                    var trialData = { "data": [{ "name": "Pratik", "group": "gold", "active": "ACTIVE", "age": "25"}] };
                    //var trialData = { "name": "Pratik", "group": "gold", "active": "ACTIVE", "age": "25" };

                    if (dataget != "error") {
                        $("#tblData").jqGrid({
                            datatype: 'local',
                            data: trialData,
                            colNames: ['Name', 'Group', 'Active', 'Age'],
                            colModel: [
                            { name: 'name', index: 1, width: 70 },
                            { name: 'group', index: 2, width: 90 },
                            { name: 'active', index: 3, width: 100 },
                            { name: 'age', index: 4, width: 80, align: "right" }
                            ],
                            rowNum: 10,
                            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
                            viewrecords: true,
                            width: 500,
                            height: 200,
                            defaults: {
                                emptyrecords: "No records to view",
                                loadtext: "Loading..."
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Error While Assigning to jQGrid!");
                    }
                },
                error: function(ex) {
                    alert("Error Occured while saving data in grid..." + ex);
                    //return false;
                }
            });
            //return false;
        }
```

The `jqGrid` is being displayed but data is not getting bind with that.

I guess the problem is surely with the `json` data.

I'm getting data from the `pagemethod` which should be passed to `jqGrid` through **`dataget`** variable.

I want to display these data into `jqGrid`.

Comment: It's not good to use separate `$.ajax` manually. jqGrid can do this for you. Nevertheless if the resulting input data for the grid looks like `var trialData = { "data": [...] };` then you should use `data: trialData.data` instead of `data: trialData`. It's your main problem. By the way the fact that you need use `dataget = $.parseJSON(data.d)` shows indirectly that your server code have a bug: you make **unneeded** manual conversion of object to JSON string. If you have ASMX web service you should just return **object** without any manual conversion to JSON. ASP.NET do all  for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you receive data? Do you receive what you expect? Just print out the data and check the format you get and you expect. jqGrid is quite well documented, take a look at some examples with fixed data and the formated string you have to pass to the grid.

Comment: yes, I'm receiving data from `pagemethod`. But not in the form of e.g. **`traildata`** variable.

Comment: Two things - alert your json inside if (dataget != "error") { ... } before loading the grid, just to know what you get. And the second - change "data: trialData" to "data: dataget".

Comment: In alert its displaying [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Parse your json first. And then refer to it's property.

```
var dataget = $.parseJSON(data).d;
```

Comment: It did not worked. Neither Alert is getting displayed.